# iOS: How is this interface achieved?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uiscrollview

Here is [the link](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/cinema-listings-guide-uk/id456423683?mt=8) for the app. Please see screenshot of first tab.

As you can see, the content is dynamically loaded via XML. Three clickable images per row.
Is this loaded on a UIScrollView ? How can you achieve this interface ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open source project that can create a grid view like that. It's called [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView). It's designed so that the API is very similar to the UITableView interface (with delegate and dataSource etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can just add UIImages to a UIScrollView to achieve this effect. You can do so dynamically at runttime. I did something similar for a fast-dial app where you can click on an image to call your contact.

Of course I don't know if they did it that way ;).

Comment: I agree it's difficult to tell what they did by screenshots. But it looks like they used a TabBarController and on the first ViewController they used a ScrollView with "paging" enabled. Then added UIImages.

Comment: Thank you guys for the hints! now ill look into adding dynamically UIimages

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a vague question to answer.

Build a custom view incorporating a Button the size of the image, allow extra space (padding) in the view around the button element (the button should be in the center of the view) make that view background clear.Then write methods to update the Button image with what ever content you downloaded. Create Delegate  to enable call backs to your viewController and viola you have the start of what you want.

Then add those views to a UIScrollView and you should have the desired affect, just ensure you adjust the scrollviews content size accordingly. As to the three column layout you should be able to work that out :)

please comment if you need more specifics than this.

Comment: Thank you Simon! ill find info now on custom views

Comment: you can either build a custom view in code - i.e. subclass UIView or use interface builder to build your custom View. Good luck!